# Translation of 食饼筒

Tags: translation

In this sentence:
台州人吃一种叫做“食饼筒”的食物。

Seems like 'food- baked thing-tube'? [Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A3%9F%E9%A5%BC%E7%AD%92), [MDBG](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E2%80%9C%E9%A3%9F%E9%A5%BC%E7%AD%92%E2%80%9D%E4%B9%9F%E5%83%8F%E9%A5%BA%E5%AD%90%E4%B8%80%E6%A0%B7) etc have no answers for this.

Comment: I did a google search and the first hit is from baidu. [百度link](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A3%9F%E9%A5%BC%E7%AD%92/5002062).

Comment: Also here:-  https://youtu.be/DYI2nnXw1-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Baidu](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A3%9F%E9%A5%BC%E7%AD%92/5002062?fr=aladdin)

食饼筒是浙江宁波石浦、台州等地的地方传统小吃，主要材料有面粉、水、粉丝及各类菜肴等，属于浙江菜。食饼筒具有面皮薄韧、作料鲜香的特点，通常在清明端午等节日食用。麦油脂与食饼筒不同，是在食饼筒基础上放入油锅煎炸，故称作麦油脂。

台州人吃一种叫做“食饼筒”的食物。
Taizhou people eat a kind of dish called "pancake roll".（卷饼）

Answer (score 0):

《汉语拼音方案》是中国人名、地名和中文文献罗马字母拼写法的统一规范，并用于汉字不便或不能使用的领域

I think maybe pinyin "shi bing-tong" is enough, just like "sushi (寿司)" in Japanese.